# Vue- not to replace the element using component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a simple button looks like

```
<button is="componentName">Click</button>
```

The `componentName` just display some information. What it is actually doing is, it is replacing the button with that information. But i want button to be there and information, is there any `replace` option like angular directive in vue component to not to replace the button? or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: It sounds like you want a directive. What does the component look like?

Comment: I can do this using directive, but is this possible using component is the question.

Comment: That depends on what the component looks like...

Comment: Sorry i didn't get that, my question in simple words are, i dont want the button mentioned above should not be replaced by the component.. The component contains simple input fields and data. I am not bothering about how the component looks like. It can be as usual component contains, template, script and all.